# how to decouple controller from Http context session

Tags: asp.net-mvc, inversion-of-control, loose-coupling

I need to store some data in session inside my action however I'm concerned about coupling my controller to the http context session, I have thought about creating a service, but is it really worth it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it isn't worth it. It is the controller that has access to the Http Context including the session. Not to mention that you already are working with an abstraction of the session: [HttpSessionStateBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpsessionstatebase.aspx) which can be easily mocked in a unit test.

There might be situations where you could have your business methods take [ICollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.icollection.aspx) as input parameter which is an interface implemented by `HttpSessionStateBase` and then have the controller pass the `Session` object to them.

Comment: So should I just call Session["my session key"] = myvalue?

Comment: @ryudice, yes, that's a perfectly valid code in a controller action.

Comment: Until you try to set up a dynamic mock for that HttpContextBase and children and figure out what a unit testing maintenance nightmare it is. Then you will appreciate why further decoupling is certainly worth it.

Comment: @Mark Seemann, no, I don't have such problems. With things like [MVCContrib TestHelper](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=TestHelper) life is easy :-)

Answer (score 0):

Especially for `ApiControllers`, build yourself a `DelegatingHandler` and push all of your goodies onto `request.Properties`. You can then retrieve them from your request whether you are testing or running live. The benefit is that you then have zero dependency on Session in your Controller.

### MessageHandler

```
public class ContextHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        // get the goodies to add onto the request
        var goodies = /* call to goodieGoodieYumYum */


        // add our goodies onto the request
        request.Properties.Add(Constants.RequestKey_Goodies, goodies);

        // pass along to the next handler
        return base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

### Controller Action

```
var goodies = (List<Goodie>)Request.Properties[Constants.RequestKey_Goodies];
```